# Using CHelper plugin in IntelliJ for a coding contest

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I quite recently discovered a coding site, with coding contests : [CodinGame](https://codingame.com), and in order to solve the problems, we have to hand them over only one file with a main (in the following example, the class `Player`), and if other classes are needed, we include them in this file.

For this purpose (and seen to be working for [another coding site](https://www.topcoder.com/)), I have downloaded intelliJ and the [plugin CHelper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/idea-chelper/wikis/MainPage.wiki) in order to put all the source files into one java file (it is supposed to be the purpose of the CHelper plugin). The problem is: I don't understand how to use/setup this plugin for my coding site. I know it should work because another user of this site has already used the plugin for this purpose.

## What I want

For a more detailed example of what I want, here is the class with a main:

```
// Class Player in file Player.java
public class Player {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Cell(1,2).toString());
    }
}
```

And this class Cell is in another java file :

```
// Class Cell in file Cell.java
public class Cell {
    int x,y;
    public Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "["+x+","+y+"]";
    }
}
```

And I would like the plugin to merge the two (or more) java files in order to have this :

```
// Generated : 2 files merged into one file: Player.java
public class Player {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Cell(1,2).toString());
    }

    // Class Cell merged in this file
    public class Cell {
        int x,y;
        public Cell(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "["+x+","+y+"]";
        }
    }
}
```

## What I achieved

I installed IntelliJ correctly, and downloaded the CHelper plugin.
I installed the toolbar menu buttons linked to TopCoder (the site that this plugin is expressly made for), but the Launch TopCoder button throws a RuntimeException : cannot run program .../javaws no such file.
With some tasks downloaded from TopCoder, I succeeded in merging 2 files into one : TaskA.java into Main.java (with templates downloaded)

## What would be ideal

If an **Eclipse** plugin could work like what I want, I would be very happy to know of it. In fact, that was what I was looking for at the beginning of my search, and I only found some plugin for the IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: If you haven't already created a project that you are using this plugin for, it's much easier to simply prefix the `class` keyword with `static`, marking this class as independent of it's enclosing class. This ensures that instances of the enclosing class are independent of instances of the classes it contains. For example, the class `Cell` in your code would be prefixed with `static`.

Comment: Well, this plugin really is for coding "properly". I would like to be able to separate classes in different files (each class a different file), and merge them with this tool into one file.
I know I should put a `static` for class `Cell` in the merged code, and I actually have it in my actual Player class (manually done).
I have something like 7 inner classes with hierarchy inside of `Player` class, and that's why I want to separate them (less dirty code), plus I want to be able to test them easily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I finally found a way to do what I wanted: the guy who had done it shared me a [link to the help](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3273?locale=en) I needed.

I am going to sum it up specifically for [CodinGame](https://www.codingame.com) here.

## I- Toolbar buttons

The important buttons to add to the menu toolbar are

- create new task
- modify task
- delete task
- Edit project settings

Now, we have some buttons in the red rectangle :
[image: toolbar IDEA]

## II- Edit settings

Then we have to `edit project settings` :

- set the default directory to your default package
- output directory is for the generated source file

[image: Editing project settings]

## III- Create task

Next thing, we have to create a new task (green "+" button) and set it up using the `advanced` option. We add the tests input and known output with the button `Edit tests`. We say we want the generated file to be called `Solution.java`, and the class where we are going to write is going to be called `CGXFormatter.java`

[image: Creating a new task]

We now have two files which have appeared in our package `.../puzzle` :

- `CGXFormatter.java` with a method `solve`, which is where we are going to read the input and give our answer in the output
- `CGXFormatter.task`, which contains the info on the test cases, etc. in order for the plugin to generate the source file

## IV- Write your solution

For example, we are just going to print "This is the result" in our `CGXFormatter` class (but we could have created another class file and called it, it would have worked by copying the definition of the class in the generated solution class). Like this :

```
package com......puzzle;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class CGXFormatter {
    public void solve(int testNumber, Scanner in, PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("This is the result");
    }
}
```

## V- Generate the solution

Last step: click on run. Then we have the directory `generated` which is created, and in it, we have the `Solution.java` file newly generated. We can read this :

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Built using CHelper plug-in
 * Actual solution is at the top
 *
 * @author XXX
 */
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputStream);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        CGXFormatter solver = new CGXFormatter();
        try {
            int testNumber = 1;
            while (true)
                solver.solve(testNumber++, in, out);
        } catch (UnknownError e) {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    static class CGXFormatter {
        public void solve(int testNumber, Scanner in, PrintWriter out) {
            out.println("This is the result");
        }

    }
}
```

## VI- Last step

Okay, there still remains a little problem: in CodinGame, the solution class should not have `public` in front of it, so just put `class Solution` instead of `public class Solution` and you're done. 
If you want, you can also put it in a script to do it automatically with a multirun (plugin to install in IDEA, also).

That's it, you're done.

## VII- Edit Octobre 2019

If the plugin complains about not finding a `net.egork....` class, you can add these steps that I found [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3273?#comment-541418)

> Update Intellij IDEA to the latest version. Secondly, you go to `File
>   -> Settings... -> Plugins` and search for the chelper plugin. It is required to run the task run configurations, and it supplies you with
>   the buttons on the toolbar, too. After you have done that, you should
>   be getting the error about impossibility to find and load class from
>   net.egork... Now you go to the jetbrains plugin site, search for
>   chelper plugin there, and download the latest zip archive. After
>   unzipping it, go to `File -> Project Structure... -> Libraries -> + ->
>   Java`, select recursively the folder you just unzipped until you get to
>   a bunch of jars that contain that missing class in the error. After
>   you have added those jars to your classpath, along with JDK, it should
>   be enough

---

*As a side note*, I remarked that the `out.println` didn't work as I intended (I don't know why), so I replaced it by `System.out.println` instead of using the proposed `out` object in the `solve` method.